# Is there any CMS that would lend itself to easily recreating this mockup?

Tags: asp.net, css, windows, content-management-system

I just finished creating a site mockup for a new version of our website.  Our current site is hand written, and all content updates are code changes.  I'd like to move our site to a CMS with as little custom styling as possible.  Based on this home page mockup is there any CMS that handles this layout better than another?

[image]

Comment: Yes, there are many. However, I fail to see how this question can be answered objectively -- at least the way it is written with no requirements other than "make it look something like this".

Comment: Most CMS software I've used has totally comparable templating systems. What you should research, more or less, is what your host can support and what kind of comfort/control ratio you're looking for. Also, it might sound kind of boring, but that could be thrown together in WordPress pretty quickly.

Comment: @SteveAdams I guess, I should reword my question. I want to know how you visualize breaking this up, say in wordpress for example. would you just write html in one big center content area, would you break it into a top, middle, bottom sections....etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@DougChamberlain I would personally divide all content by context; almost all blocks on the page would be derived from different files which were called into the home page template. The rest of the site may use a different template, but may still call the same blocks of content - This is a key part of why we'd design this way. This can be accomplished in any CMS; it's more a design principle than a feature these days.

For example, the red items in [my overlaid mockup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSBbA.png) are includes, blue would be hardcoded, and green could be handled either way depending on your perceived uses for the content. Each include (red) would be a very generic php-html file, collecting data from different resources (Mostly your database) which could be adapted to different layout requirements.

Example of why we do this: You might design the search bar so that when you included it, it was inside of a container which could have the class 'longSearch' or 'searchBoxLarge' or 'searchBoxSmall' (Or whatever) which would dynamically produce the long search bar you've shown or a larger/small box to place in the right side of the footer perhaps. We'd design these included files to be very adaptable and reusable. Each time you include the search bar, it takes a single line of code (That's awesome), and each time it has an issue or needs an update, you only need to work on the file in one place.

Finally, all of these widgets, or components, or whatever you might want to call them, would live inside templates, which belonged to pages. Each page would have a set template (A blog style template, a generic content style template, a home page template, etc) which would accomodate the type of content that page was supposed to hold.

Any CMS is capable of this, but as I mentioned, WordPress is perfectly suitable, documents this layout method well, is free, and easy to learn with.

I apologize if my explanation here isn't what you were hoping for! I'm aiming to be helpful, but it can be difficult over the internet sometimes. Feel free to ask more or have me iterate over some points a little better.

Comment: Great answer, this is really what I needed.  This is my first experience going from mockup to website.

Comment: Good luck with it! It's a lot of fun once you get the hang of it.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of variables other than just layout should play into choosing a CMS. One, what's the environment it will live in, windows or linux? Two, who will be the developers and what skills do they have? Three, who will be the content managers, developers, secretaries, other? Four, how easy is it add customization to it? And last, can I get my data back out easily if I want to move to another CMS?

There are literally hundreds of CMS's out there, and most do pretty much the same. They allow a template to be made, content pages be created off the template and the links for each page to be hooked up to another page.

Instead of just listing a huge amount of CMS names, just think of the above questions, answer them for your specific situation and then you should be able to choose a CMS which will help manage your content.

Good luck, and hope you find a solution that will work for you.